# Combine two fields in Ms Access through queries

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax-error

have two fields in MS Access, one is a "date/time" datatype and the other a "short text" datatype.

the date/time datatype is a date format: mm/dd/yyyy
the short text datatype is a time 24hr format: 2100

I'm trying to combine the two fields into one without changing their format. So far I've done this: 
1) First adding a semicolon for the time:
`Format(TimeSerial(Left([Trip_output].[REP_TIME],2),Right([Trip_output].[REP_TIME],2),0),"Short Time")`

2) Combining the two fields, date & time:
`Format([Trip_output].[REP_DATE],"mm/dd/yyyy")+ ([Trip_output].[REP_TIME],"hh:nn"))`

Constraints:
- I need to use only queries to make changes
- I cannot change through design view

What is the best way to combine them to get it to this format: " mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn" ?

Comment: Why not just add them together? If they are truly both Date/Time format, then just `[Rep_Time] + [Rep_Date]` will do the trick.

Comment: That's what I did,I did as an update query in the Date/Time column of the same table and the time changes to AM/PM format instead of 24hr format

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add a date/time date and a string time. You must convert the string time to date/time time first. So, in a query:

```
REP_DATETIME: [REP_DATE]+TimeValue(Format([REP_TIME, "@@\:@@"))
```